# Capture RSID into a prop using DTM

Tags: adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics, web-analytics

I'm a bit new to Adobe's Dynamic Tag Manager, so I'm looking for a little help.

I need to be able to track the report suite ID defined by SiteCatalyst. DTM was somewhat implemented prior to me taking on the project - so no data layers or even standard s code has been implemented.

I get how I can make calls using the _satellite functions; however, I'm not able to find one that will allow me to capture the RSID.

Can I even do this in DTM using some sort of data element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reference s.account within the AA tool (Custom Page Code Section) it will return the RSID.

```
s.prop1 = s.account
```

Hope this helps.
Mark

Comment: Tried to add it as a data element instead of adding it to the Custom Page Code. I need to think about it like the old s.code days when we worked together. Cheers!!

Comment: Also remember that s.account doesn't have a global scope within DTM. That's why calling s.account directly within a DE won't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are only a few _satellite that are "safe" to use.  By safe I mean that Adobe has stated they will not change the behavior of without any notice.  I would strongly advise not digging through the functions for a solution.

I am curious on why you need the RSID, since the beacon will only go to the RSID that you setup in DTM.  If you are using custom code to dynamically set the s.account variable you could just set an evar or prop at the same time.

Comment: I need the RSID to segment each country site within a global report suite. There isn't any page code on the site, other then the DTM library. Your comment about setting an eVar and sProp is the route I would want to take, but I'm not sure where the account ID is located. I'm use to the standard page code and using the s_code.js where I could set the account ID; however, I'm not exactly sure where that's set in DTM.